# Moderator refused to add tag "censorship" to the tag list for posts on meta.skeptics

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation

A moderator has **refused** to add the word **"censorship"** to the list of available tags for posts.

I asked that in my original post at the end [Too much power given to the moderators on Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2726/too-much-power-given-to-the-moderators-on-skeptics)

and also one more time below his answer in the comments.

Here is his response:

> I'm reluctant to do that because I don't think it is censorship under any reasonable definition of that tag, but I didn't really want to get into a debate about whether I am censoring your claims of censorship. The word has been mentioned sufficiently that anyone searching for it should find it here.

Please, if you are a moderator or do have more than 300 points add it there.

The problem of this moderator is that he probably doesn't like the possibility of having the tag "censorship"in the future tags at all.

But what he/she likes is not the right attitude of a skeptic.

Every objective skeptic have to consider the possibility that even censorship on this site is possible and could happened in the past, today or in the future.

Therefore having this tag is an essential improvement for the users and moderators.

Comment: We don't discuss single users on this site, so I've removed all references to a specific user. Please don't conflate the policies that moderators follow with the moderator intentions (which you know nothing about).

Comment: @Sklivvz I somewhat disagree with that: we absolutely discuss single users when discussing their (alleged) misconduct. Otherwise, how could we scrutinise moderators’ power abuse? However, this obviously doesn’t apply here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ["no airing of dirty laundry in public, no bringing up issues faced as a moderator in unrelated discussions, questions raised by other members of the public answered with as little detail as possible"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator)

Comment: @Sklivvz “in unrelated discussions” is obviously key here (I also disagree with some of the finer points of the moderator removal procedure etc. but that’s a different discussion).

Comment: @KonradRudolph My personal take is that discussing *behaviors* is fine, discussing *people* is abusive. There's no need to name the moderator in question in order to discuss the behavior and this has two benefits: disarms personal attacks and allows the discussion to be potentially more applicable than the specific case.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way of adding a tag to the “list of acceptable tags” as far as I’m aware.

The only way of doing so is adding the tag to an actual question. Oddthinking refused to add the tag to your other question because he – rightly – observed that the other question wasn’t about censorship at all: you had simply misunderstood the editing process.

But as soon as there is a question where the tag [censorship](/questions/tagged/censorship) makes legitimate sense, the tag will be added.

> The problem of this moderator is that he probably doesn't like the possibility of having the tag "censorship"in the future tags at all.

We don’t really care one way or another: The (non-)existence of a tag won’t prevent a subject’s discussion.

Comment: You are saying that you (moderators) have no control of adding/removing/editing tags that are popping up in autosuggestion box for a question? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @Derfder We can remove and edit tags, but not add them.

Comment: How come that some editors/moderators in the past were so kind and added tags for me, because I didn't have 300 points. It happened on Stackoverflow and Travel or Physics, not sure. But I witnessed that multiple times on my posts. Are you sure you cannot add tags? I can find the posts, but, please before I am doing that, are you sure you cannot add tags in my post?

Comment: @Derfder Like I wrote, we *can* add tags *to specific questions*. Oddthinking didn’t do it in your particular case because he didn’t think that the tag applied (and I agree): your question wasn’t about censorship.

Comment: "your question wasn’t about censorship" I disagree, but whatever. However, this question is 100% about censorship, so, please add the tag censorship there. Thank you.

Comment: I think you may not know how the autosuggestion/autocompelte works. Once you have created the tag, it will pop up whenever somebody type cen.. or cens... and censorship pops up in the list of available tags. this way the whole comunity could benefit from better categorization of common tags here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags

Comment: So, please add the tag "censorship" to the list of existing tags by adding it to this question. This question is 100% about censorship.

Comment: @Derfder No, this question is about tagging.

Answer (score 3):

[censorship](/questions/tagged/censorship) would be a bad tag, that is the main reason why nobody has added it. The actual issue is [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) or maybe [editing](/questions/tagged/editing). Your meta post is about your disagreement with the way your post was edited and certain moderator actions like locking the post. Those are the kind of tags that would be useful.

Censorship is not a neutral term, you can of course call the moderator actions censorship in your post, but the tag system is not the place for such things.

Comment: "Censorship is not a neutral term", nor is the subjective censorship on skeptics.

Comment: Racism and antisemitism is a bad thing too, but we need to call things how they are. **Would you call the Holocaust moderation too?** I hope you wouldn't!